# Calculating day of the week XSL

Tags: xslt-1.0

Trying to calculate day of the week number from date. Found some examples in the internet, but  instead of day of the week number i see this : NaN.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="date">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:call-template name="date-format">
        <xsl:with-param name="date-time" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="date-format">
    <xsl:param name="date-time"/>
    <xsl:param name="date" select="substring-before($date-time,'T')"/>
    <xsl:param name="year" select="substring-before($date,'-')"/>
    <xsl:param name="month" 
          select="substring-before(substring-after($date,'-'),'-')"/>
    <xsl:param name="day" select="substring-after(substring-after($date,'-'),'-')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="a" select="floor((14 - $month) div 12)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year - $a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$month + 12 * $a - 2"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="($day + $y + floor($y div 4) - floor($y div 100) 
    + floor($y div 400) + floor((31 * $m) div 12)) mod 7"/>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="test2.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>


<document>
  <date>2013-01-01</date>
  <date>2013-05-24</date>
  <date>2013-12-25</date>
  <date>1957-07-13</date>
  <date>1776-07-04</date>
</document>
```

Comment: What is the expected result of transforming your input example?

Comment: integer numbers from 0 to 6(sunday to saturday)

Comment: Yes, but where do you want to put these numbers?

Comment: On an empty page. Just for expamle.

Comment: When i run this code it shows me NaNNaNNaNNaNNaN. So i expect to see something like 34354 on white page

Comment: "*i expect to see something like 34354 on white page*" That doesn't seem very useful, but I have posted a stylesheet that does just that. Hopefully, you'll be able to make your own adjustments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="date">
    <xsl:call-template name="day-of-week">
        <xsl:with-param name="date" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="day-of-week">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>

    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date,1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($date, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 9, 2)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="a" select="floor((14 - $month) div 12)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year + 4800 - $a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$month + 12*$a - 3"/>

    <xsl:variable name="JDN" select="$day + floor((153*$m + 2) div 5) + 365*$y + floor($y div 4) - floor($y div 100) + floor($y div 400) - 32045" />

    <xsl:value-of select="($JDN + 1) mod 7" />
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input example:

```
<document>
  <date>2013-01-01</date>
  <date>2013-05-24</date>
  <date>2013-12-25</date>
  <date>1957-07-13</date>
  <date>1776-07-04</date>
</document>
```

will return the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
25364
```

---

**Note**:

The main problem with your attempt is this:

```
<xsl:param name="date" select="substring-before($date-time,'T')"/>
```

Your input has dates, not date-times, and they do not contain "T".

Comment: Why not just make it "- 32044"?

Comment: @LadyCygnus Because Julian Day Number is a standard.