# How to get the weekday from a date with XSLT?

Tags: date, xslt

I am using the variable below to get the current day in a week for my input date. The expression below worked well, however, one of the software I am using to generate the final output, is not able to support the xs:integer and format-date as below.

`<xsl:variable name="day" select="xs:integer(format-date($field, '[F1]'))"/>`

the field will look like this: `2020-04-01`. In this case, the result will be `3`

Is there any other way I can obtain the day position in a week, without using xs:integer and format-date, for any date my field is going to take?
Thank you!

Comment: I presume you mean your processor is limited to XSLT 1.0? If so see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33499595/3016153

Comment: Or:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60129696/3016153

Comment: Thank you! The first solution works well on my side. Thanks