# How to retrieve day name from the date in XSL 1.0 version

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

`How to retrieve day name from the date in XSL 1.0 version.
for example if i pass 2023-09-27 as input it should return Wednesday or Wed.

Kindly share working sample code for XSL 1.0 version only.
We already tried the below function and giving the 'Parse error in format date function'

```
`<ReqdExctnDt>
      <xsl:variable name="Pmtdate" select="PaymentDate"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-date($Pmtdate,'[FNn,*-3]:')" />
 </ReqdExctnDt>
```

`Expected Output: if i pass PaymentDate as 2023-09-27 as input it should return Wednesday or Wed.`

Comment: Find out which XSLT 1.0 processor exactly you use and check its documentation as to which format its proprietary `format-date` function expects, if there is one. XSLT/XPath 1.0 don't have a standard one so unless a specific processor has a proprietary extension or allows calling into the underlying platform (like Java or .NET) or allows you embed or run code in e.g. Java(Script), PHP there is no function.

Comment: Some XSLT 1.0 processors support https://exslt.github.io/date/functions/day-name/index.html.

Comment: If you're limited to pure XSLT 1.0, start by finding the day-of-week as a number, using for example the method shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60129696/3016153 or the one used here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33499595/3016153. Then it's a simple matter of converting the number to the corresponding name.

Comment: If you're limited to XSLT 1.0, why is the question also tagged as `xslt-2.0`??